# How should I deal with old black mastic before installing floor tiles?

Tags: tile, floor, adhesive

I will be removing wood floor tiles that wee installed over old VCT tile which have black mastic on them. I can remove the wood and VCT with no issues, but I do not want to have to remove the old glue. Is there a product that I can apply over the glue before I install new tile in thin set? The sub floor is concrete.

Comment: Have you checked the mastic and tile for asbestos?

Comment: Call up the thinset manufacturer; they will tell you what they recommend.